# How to get the value of a span inside a li using Python Selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

I am trying to get the value of SCN from my HTML page which is in this format-

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="hs-customerdata hs-customerdata-pvalues">
            <ul>
                <li class="hs-attribute">
                    <map-hs-label-value map-hs-lv-label="ACCOUNTINFO.SCN" map-hs-lv-value="89862530">
                    <span class="hs-attribute-label" hs-context-data="" translate="" hs-channel="abcd" hs-device="desktop">SCN:</span>
                    <span ng-bind-html="value | noValue | translate : params" class="hs-attribute-value" context-data="" map-v-key="89862530" map-v-params="" hs-channel="abcd" hs-device="desktop">
                    89862530</span>
                    </map-hs-label-value>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As of now I tried different ways, but unable to reach the span and get the SCN value.

I tried -

```
scn = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[@class = 'hs-attribute-value']")
```

which gives ElementNotFound error. The closest I have come to is -

```
div_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="hs-customerdata hs-customerdata-personal"]/ul/li[@class="hs-attribute"]')
```

And then when I do -

```
print(div_element.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

I get -

```
<map-hs-label-value map-hs-lv-label="ACCOUNTINFO.SCN" map-hs-lv-value="{{::customerData.details.scn}}"></map-hs-label-value>
```

But I am not able to go beyound this. I am new to using Webdriver and not able to figure out this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `SCN` i.e. **89862530** is reflected in 3 different places and you can extract it from either of the places inducing *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `<map-hs-label-value>` tag with `map-hs-lv-value` attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located()((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='hs-customerdata hs-customerdata-pvalues']/ul/li/map-hs-label-value"))).get_attribute("map-hs-lv-value"))
  ```
- `<span>` tag with `map-v-key` attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located()((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='hs-customerdata hs-customerdata-pvalues']/ul/li/map-hs-label-value//span[@class='hs-attribute-value']"))).get_attribute("map-v-key"))
  ```
- `<span>` tag with text as `89862530`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located()((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='hs-customerdata hs-customerdata-pvalues']/ul/li/map-hs-label-value//span[@class='hs-attribute-value']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```

Comment: Great answer and very well explained ! It worked like a charm...accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can locate the [`span`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) element with text `SCN:` as `//span[text()='SCN:']`
2. The element with the text of `89862530` would be the [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) of the element from point 1
3. Putting everything together:

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='SCN:']/following-sibling::span").text
   ```

   Demo:

   [image]

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Comment: I am still getting ElementNotFound with this.  I think the WebDriverWait is required here. That solved the issue. Thanks for the documentation links though.